# How to open an S3 pre-signed URL in another tab?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How do I open an S3 file in another tab and not download it? I have this feature that generates a pre-signed URL. The front-end then opens this URL. However, what I would like to happen is to open the file in another tab so that the user can see the file before downloading it.

**Backend**

```
  static async downloadFile(req, res, next) {
    s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
      Bucket: process.env.BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: req.body.fileName
    }, (error, url) => {
      if (error) {
        res.status(403).json({
          err
        })
      } else {
        res.status(200).json({
          url
        })
      }
    })
  }
```

Frontend

```
User.downloadFile(fileName) // HTTP request was made in another file using axios
  .then((res) => {
    window.open(res.data.url)
  })
```

Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: The fact that it _downloads_, is not specifically triggered by anything in the code you have shown - so presumably, that happens because of the response headers of that signed URL. So you would have to go and check the API documentation, if there is any parameter you can set to not make this a "forced download."

Comment: Also, trying to open a new window from within an asynchronous callback, will get caught by the popup blocker in most browsers these days. The attempt to open a new window must be _directly_ tied to a user interaction (such as a click) - so the general workaround for that would be to open the popup directly, and then either have the code that requests the URL load in there to begin with; or open a "dummy" popup first, and then assign the new URL when you get your API response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set contentType of the image to the correct one while uploading the image to s3. like, set contentType to `image/png` if your image has `.png` format. If the contentType is not correct or not set then the image will be directly downloaded instead of displaying it in the browser. This should solve your problem.